# Remove trailing slash for nginx WordPress multisite

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite, trailing-slash

I have installed WordPress multisite in sub-directory `abc.com/en/`. I want to remove the trailing slash for SEO purposes. So pages like `abc.com/en/xxx/` will be 301 redirected to `abc.com/en/xxx` without a trailing slash.

After checking many resources (I am using Nginx), I found the code below to be working for all pages except the multisite homepage `abc.com/en/`. WordPress always 301 redirects `abc.com/en` to `abc.com/en/` with a trailing slash, so it will cause a redirect loop.

```
if (!-d $request_filename) {
   rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; 
}
```

So how can I remove the trailing slash for the `en/` too? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

add this line to functions.php

This this line you can fix redirect from domain.com/page to domain.com/page/ with trail slash

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Please don't forget clear cache or test on clean browser

Comment: it works! this code remove the wordpress auto-redirect.